# Dealing with "cracks" in the unary_union of several imprecise Polygons?

Tags: python, shapely

I used `shapely.ops.unary_union` on a number of 6-sided `shapely.geometry.Polygon`s, and obtained the following shape `A`:

[image: An irregular polygon shaped with a "honeycomb" shape, with "cracks" in it.]

Note how there are two "cracks" in the upper part. These are not intended, and are presumably caused by some floating-point edge cases.

If you construct another shape `B` that sits inside of `A`, and if `A` happens to intersect one of these "cracks", then `A.covers(B)` will be `False`!

In my particular case, this leads to a test suite failure, because `A.covers(B)` is supposed to be an invariant. Therefore I need to deal with this somehow. Is there some algorithm I can use to "seal" these cracks?

In practice, these "cracks" will not affect the functioning of the application, because we only care about the outer border of `A` covering `B`. Thus I am open to solutions that adjust the individual hexagons in order to make the cracks go away by introducing overlaps.

However, I cannot accept the *outer* border of this shape changing, because that would actually no longer be testing the application as it is intended to be used.

To summarize, I want the outcome to look like this (my hand-edited version):

[image: The same polygon, without any cracks]

Comment: Simplest fix would be to [buffer](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.buffer) the polygon by some very small value, buffer it by the negative of that value. The effect would be to expand the polygon, swallowing any small cracks, then shrink it again to get the edges back where they were. Would that work for you?

Comment: @NickODell are you saying that I should buffer the individual hexagons, take the union of the buffered hexagons, and then shrink the union by the amount of the buffer?

Comment: Yes, but I was suggesting doing the buffer after the union has been done, but I think your way is the same.

Comment: I see! I had assumed that expanding the union and then un-expanding it would just leave the cracks untouched. Can you post this information as an answer? I will accept it once I test it and confirm that it works @NickODell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can fix this by buffering and un-buffering the shape.

Here's an example of a polygon with a small crack:

```py
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
bad_polygon = Polygon([[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0.4999], [0.5, 0.5], [1, 0.5001], [1, 1], [0, 1], [0, 0]])
```

[image: polygon crack]

To fix it, expand the shape slightly, and contract it the same amount, using the [buffer()](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.buffer) method.

```py
tol = 1e-4
bad_polygon.buffer(tol).buffer(-tol)
```

The value `tol` must be at least as large as half the distance across the crack at the crack's widest point.

[image: no crack]

Comment: Holy shit, simple and amazing! Aside from fixing cracks, this also merges overlapping polygons within a multi-polygon--something that was necessary before intersecting two multi-polygons. Every union operation I tried was throwing fits. Thanks, Nick!

Comment: This is the standard (and usually best) solution, but note that this operations smooths the corners of your boundary (that you didn't want to change).  The amount of smoothing in this case is tiny, because the buffer is tiny.  Whether that is truly negligible depends on your application.

Comment: @AaronBramson That's true, but note that only concave corners will be changed. Convex corners will not be smoothed.